# How to count multiple values occurencies from table and pick max

Tags: mysql, sql, select, count, max

I'm struggling with making a proper mysql query. Here's the table:

```
**survey_result**
question_id
header_id
answer
```

Where answer is int in (0,1,2,3,4,5) range. I'd like to make a query, where i will count how many times for specific id, a specific answer occurred. So for question_id = 1 i'd like to see:

```
question_id answer occurence_number
1           0      12
1           1      20
1           2      34
1           3      5
1           4      9
1           5      15
```

And most likely i'd like to pick an answer with either most or least occurrences. But that's the second part, i'm struggling with first one.

With huge help with first statement i managed to finish it off, this is how working version looks:

```
select question_id, max(occurence_number) FROM
(select question_id, answer, count(*) as occurence_number
from survey_result
group by question_id, answer
order by question_id asc, occurence_number desc) as results
GROUP BY question_id
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
SELECT
  Question_id,
  answer,
  COUNT(answer)
FROM Questions
WHERE question_id = 1
GROUP BY Question_ID, answer;
```

For the second part, to get the answer with the max occurrence number:

```
SELECT
  Question_id,
  answer,
  COUNT(answer)
FROM questions
GROUP BY Question_ID,  
         answer
HAVING COUNT(answer) = (SELECT MAX(TheCount)
                        FROM
                        (
                           SELECT COUNT(answer) AS TheCount
                           FROM questions
                           GROUP BY answer
                        ) AS t) ;
```

### [SQL Fiddle Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/01dd7/13)

**Or:** Simply:

```
SELECT
  Question_id,
  answer,
  COUNT(answer) Occurrance
FROM Questions
WHERE question_id = 1
GROUP BY Question_ID, answer
ORDER BY Occurrance DESC 
LIMIT 1;
```

But this will give you only one value. *However*, if there are answers with the same max occurrence times use the previous one.

Comment: Big thanks i'm still working on it cause second query returns 0 results for some reason

Comment: I've found a bit simplier for me answer which is: select question_id, max(occurence_number) FROM
(select question_id, answer, count(*) as occurence_number
from survey_result
group by question_id, answer
order by question_id asc, occurence_number desc) as results
GROUP BY question_id but you helped me a lot, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

```
select question_id, answer, count(*) as occurence_number
from survey_result
group by question_id, answer
order by question_id asc, occurence_number desc;
```

Comment: This works brilliant altho i can't figure out how to select max by question_id from your query

Answer (score 0):

SELECT
  Question_id,
  answer,
  COUNT(answer)
FROM Questions
WHERE = 1
GROUP BY (Question_ID, answer)